# How to groupby a two dimentional list by a key with a condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, grouping, python-itertools

I have this code:

```
from itertools import groupby
a = [[1,'n'],[2,'n'],[3,'n'],[4,'d'],[5,'n']]
b = [list(group) for key, group in groupby(a, lambda x: x[1] if x[1]=='n' else None)]
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[[[1, 'n'], [2, 'n'], [3, 'n']], [[4, 'd']], [[5, 'n']]]
```

Expected output:

```
[[[1, 'n'], [2, 'n'], [3, 'n']], [[5, 'n']]]
```

Comment: you mean to _filter_ elements, not to group them. where should the other elements go?

Comment: you mean by value? the expected output shows you are filtering by value 'n'.

Comment: filter: `b = [x for x in a if x[1]=='n']`

Comment: yes, by value 'n', the groupby has a key value where I can group the list by the second value, but I want also to group them if the value is 'n'

Comment: You simply want to filter the list?

Comment: You mean to filter it first?

Comment: I mean if you only want sublists with an `n` as their second elements, as @Jean-FrançoisFabre suggests

Comment: But can I do this in the groupby list comprehension?

Comment: It seems overly complicated when you can use a simple list comprehension

Comment: I want to get the largest group in a row of two dimentional lists by their second value if it is 'n'

Comment: For example: when I get the expected output ([[[1, 'n'], [2, 'n'], [3, 'n']], [[5, 'n']]]) I can write a code that finds the larget group of 'n', that is [[1, 'n'], [2, 'n'], [3, 'n']]

Comment: did you considered numpy array to use ? b = np.array(a)
print(b[np.where(b[:,1] == "n")])

Answer (score 5):

You put the `if` in the wrong place. It should be a filter to the list comprehension, not part of the `groupby` key function.

```
>>> [list(group) for key, group in groupby(a, lambda x: x[1]) if key=='n']
[[[1, 'n'], [2, 'n'], [3, 'n']], [[5, 'n']]]
```

Comment: That is perfect, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This finds the longest group, without knowing `'n'` to be it:

```
a = [[1,'n'],[2,'n'],[3,'n'],[4,'d'],[5,'n'],[6,'q'],[6,'q'],[6,'q'],[6,'q'],[6,'q']]

k = max( (list(grp) for key,grp in groupby(a,lambda x:x[1])), key=len)  
print(k)
```

Output:

```
[[6, 'q'], [6, 'q'], [6, 'q'], [6, 'q'], [6, 'q']]
```

If there are two groups of same length, the first one (irrespect. of 2nd element) is outputted.

---

This is a "unrolled" variant spezialized in finding the longest group of elements with `'n'` as second element - using [max()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

```
a = [[1,'n'],[2,'n'],[3,'n'],[4,'d'],[5,'n']]

result = [[]]
for e in a:
    if e[1] == 'n':             # if 'n' 2nd element, add to list
        result[-1].append(e)
    elif result[-1]:
        result.append([])       # if not, append new sublist

longest = max(result, key=len)  # get the longest one from all lists

print(longest)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 'n'], [2, 'n'], [3, 'n']]
```

Doku:

- [max(iterable, *[, key, default])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)

Comment: That is not what I mean. I want to find the largest group of 'n' that go one after another:
    
    [[1, 'n'], [2, 'n'], [3, 'n']]

Comment: @IgorDragushhak  - sounds as if that fact is missing from your question - please edit.

Comment: [5, 'n'] can't be in that group as it is divided by [4, 'd']